# Conversão de Procedures

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

Alguém conhece ou sabe um jeito mas fácil de fazer uma migração de stored-procedures do SQL-Server para o Oracle.

Comment: Porque toda pergunta no SO precisa ser um tratado ? Uma pergunta pode ser sucinta e se ater ao escopo do site , esta na minha modesta opinião e com a devida vênia é uma.

Answer (score 2):

Tem, conhecendo bem como funciona cada banco :)
Essa sem dúvida é a melhor forma, ter um ou dois profissionais que entendam bem, principalmente se a *procedure* usar recursos bem específicos, como *hints*.

Mas, pra ajudar, tem esse site que converte online a maioria da sintaxe básica de vários bancos de dados, não só `oracle` e `sql-server`:  http://www.sqlines.com/online

Sugiro colocar a query lá que vai ajudar muito, deixando funcional, ai você se foca no nas coisas muito específicas. Pra ajudar nisso, tem esse ótimo material comparando os dois bancos de dados, em inglês: [ss oracle compared](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10405_01/appdev.120/e10379/ss_oracle_compared.htm)

Comment: Você saberia me informar se existe algum software que ajude? Mesmo sendo pago

Comment: infelizmente não conheço nenhum Leonardo